# Override mat-list-text

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a problem to access the mat-list-text class from material List.

I'm trying to override this class in order to change overflow from hidden to visible.

[image]

But I can't do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
.mat-list-text {
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

If this does not work, go with `::ng-deep`

Comment: Ok It works with ng-deep... I tried this without !important. What is the difference ?

Comment: ng-deep overrides all the styles and applies the style for all the child components. ng host does the same for parent element. I guess !important would do the work.